# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject. Works in Query editor

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is my controller:

```
 public with sharing class PKB_DataForScraping_MobileController extends PKB_ComponentControllerBase{
    public Id artId {get;set
        {
            artId = value;
        }
    }
    public String artTitle {get;set;}
    public String artSummary {get;set;}
    public FAQ__kav faqAnswer {
        get {
            List<FAQ__kav> faq;
            try {
                faq = [select Answer__c from FAQ__kav where PublishStatus = 'Online' and KnowledgeArticleId = :artId limit 1];
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return faq[0];
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@isTest
public class PKB_Tests_Mobile {
    public static Id faqId = 'kA0C0000000CgQtKAK';
    static testMethod void retriveFaqAnswer() {
        System.debug('Retriving FAQ answer: ');
        PKB_DataForScraping_MobileController dsm = new PKB_DataForScraping_MobileController(); 
        dsm.artId = faqId;
        FAQ__kav faq = dsm.faqAnswer;
        System.debug('answer: ' + faq.Answer__c);
    }
}
```

There are other question like mine, but I have tried all approach (using list, putting inside try catch).. my concern is why is this not returning any result?? 
When I try the SOQL in query editor, I positively get a result.. why not in APEX??
I already verified that field level security is enabled for the profile that this class is using. Please help.

Comment: Tests do not [see data already in an org by default](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm) and usually would insert the data that they need to test. Not sure what the best pattern for `__kav` objects is (i.e. whether they can be inserted) but a short term fix should be to use the [@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) option to see the test run all the way through and then see if you can insert the objects instead.

Comment: Can you output the value of artId with a system.debug just before the soql query ?

Comment: Keith: I get no results even after using SeeAllData=true

Comment: Mihai: Yes I get the exact value of artId like I assigned

Comment: Yes its a custom object, there is no __c. Like I said in the post, the SOQL produces result when I try in query editor but not via the test or using VF.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090k9IAA

Comment: Mihai: Changing the API version of the test gave me a result.. now need to check with VF pages. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help, I will add the link as an answer and mark it as solved so others can benefit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the class version as indicated here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090k9IAA will solve the issue